# How many times does fib(3) gets called when we call fib(6) using the recursive approach to Fibonacci series?

Tags: c++, c, function, recursion, fibonacci

I came across the problem

> How many times does fib(n) gets called when we call fib(k) using the recursive approcah to Fibonacci series? (where k>n)

Here fib(n) is the function which gives nth fibonacci number using the recursive approach:-

```
    int fib(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return n; 
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

**MY TRY:**
I tried to do it for the particular case where n=3 and k=6. I found the answer to be fib(6-3+1) = fib(3+1) = 3. The following flowchart shows it.
[image]
Does it generalise too?
Is it correct to state that the answer to this problem is fib(k-n+1)?

P.S. Please do not just post some code in answer! Please try to think in terms of a general formulla.

Comment: As you have the tree for k=6. If you take n=2, thus by the formula fib($k-$n), we get the number of occurrence of f(2)=4, but it's evident from the figure that f(2) occurs 5 times. Thereby violating fib($k-$n).

Comment: It does, but it fails for k=7 and n=2. The expected value is 8 in that case. Value from the formula is 6

Comment: What makes you think that 7-2+1 = 8? @Kabir

Comment: Moving away from the problem, if your only target is to find the no. of occurrences, you can use dynamic programming to solve it by traversing the entire tree

Comment: @DebarghaRoy I am saying that fib(7-2+1) = fib(6) = 8.

Comment: okay! misunderstood it!

Comment: I am curious about the downvote.

Comment: Where is a downvote?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy This question was downvoted!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218835/discussion-between-debargha-roy-and-kabir).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct. The `fib(k - n + 1)` will give number of times `fib(n)` called when calculating `fib(k)` recursively, where `k > n` and this works for `n = 0` as well.

When we write code to calculate `k`<sup>th</sup> [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), we give seed values `fib(0) = 0` and `fib(1) = 1` which is also the terminating condition when using recursion.

From [Generalizations of Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers):

[image]

Consider this example, assume that **not** given the seed values `f(0) = 0` and `f(1) = 1`:

```
  // read f(x) as fibonacci(x)
                                   f(4)
                                    |
                  -------------------------------------
                  |                                   |
                 f(3)                                f(2)
                  |                                   |
          -----------------                  --------------------
          |               |                  |                  |
         f(2)            f(1)               f(1)               f(0)
          |               |                  |                  |
      ---------      ----------         ----------         -----------
      |       |      |        |         |        |         |         |
     f(1)    f(0)   f(0)     f(-1)     f(0)     f(-1)     f(-1)     f(-2)
      |       |      |        |         |        |         |         |
    -----   -----  -----    -----     -----    -----     -----     -----
    |   |   |   |  |   |    |   |     |   |    |   |     |   |     |   |
  f(0) f(-1)|   |f(-1)f(-2) |   |  f(-1) f(-2) |   |  f(-2) f(-3)  |   |
    |       |   |           |   |              |   |               |   |
    |    f(-1) f(-2)     f(-2) f(-3)        f(-2) f(-3)         f(-3) f(-4)
  -----
  |   |
f(-1) f(-2)
 .....
 ..... and so on
```

Now lets calculate the number of `f(n)` calls for `f(4)` using `f(4 - n + 1)`, where `n < 4`:

```
n = 3  ==>  f(4 - 3 + 1)   ==> f(2) ==> 1  --
n = 2  ==>  f(4 - 2 + 1)   ==> f(3) ==> 2   |
n = 1  ==>  f(4 - 1 + 1)   ==> f(4) ==> 3   |-  Number of time f(n) called when calculating f(4)
n = 0  ==>  f(4 - 0 + 1)   ==> f(5) ==> 5   |   cross check it with recursive call trace shown above
n = -1 ==>  f(4 -(-1) + 1) ==> f(6) ==> 8  --
.....
..... and so on
```

### EDIT:

The bidirectional sequence of fibonacci is (based on formula in above link):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
... f(−4) | f(−3) | f(−2) | f(−1) | f(0) | f(1) | f(2) | f(3) | f(4) | f(5) | f(6) ....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
... −3    | 2     | −1    | 1     | 0    | 1    | 1    | 2    | 3    | 5    | 8 ....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From this sequence, `fib(-3) = 2` and `fib(-4) = -3`. Lets use these values as terminating condition of recursion instead of `fib(0) = 0` and `fib(1) = 1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n) {
        if (n == -3) {
                return 2;
        }

        if (n == -4) {
                return -3;
        }

        printf ("recursive call - fib(%d) + fib(%d)\n", n - 1, n - 2);
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

// This is a test program to prove OP number of calls to f(n)
// when calculating f(k), where n < k

int main(void) {
        int n;
        printf ("Enter a number (>= -4):\n");
        scanf ("%d", &n);

        // Input less than -4 not allowed as -4 is
        // the least seed value provided which is also  
        // a terminating condition of recusive function
        // calculating kth fibonacci number

        if (n < -4) {
                return 0;
        }

        printf("Fibonacci Number at location %d in series : %d\n", n, fib(n));    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out 
Enter a number (>= -4):
4
recursive call - fib(3) + fib(2)
recursive call - fib(2) + fib(1)
recursive call - fib(1) + fib(0)
recursive call - fib(0) + fib(-1)
recursive call - fib(-1) + fib(-2)
recursive call - fib(-2) + fib(-3)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-2) + fib(-3)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-1) + fib(-2)
recursive call - fib(-2) + fib(-3)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(0) + fib(-1)
recursive call - fib(-1) + fib(-2)
recursive call - fib(-2) + fib(-3)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-2) + fib(-3)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(1) + fib(0)
recursive call - fib(0) + fib(-1)
recursive call - fib(-1) + fib(-2)
recursive call - fib(-2) + fib(-3)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-2) + fib(-3)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-1) + fib(-2)
recursive call - fib(-2) + fib(-3)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
recursive call - fib(-3) + fib(-4)
Fibonacci Number at location 4 in series : 3
```

In the output, the number of times `f(0)` called when calculating `f(4)` is same as the one calculated with `f(k - n + 1)` where `k = 4` and `n = 0` (satisfying condition `k > n`) and `0` is not the least value.

Comment: Correct! But here the fib function just stops for fib(0). The point is that it wont work for the least fibonacci wherever we stop. If the base case would be fib(1) = fib(2) = 1 then the number of calls to fib(1) by fib(k) won't be the same as fib(k-1+1).

Comment: @kabir that's because of the condition in your program `if (n <= 1) return n; ` which returns `0` for `fib(0)` and `1` for `fib(1)`. So, when `n` is `1` the recursion terminates.

Comment: @kabir The seed value will have impact on number of calls to `fib()` function for least values. The point I want to prove is `f(k - n +1)` for calculating `f(n)` calls is correct assuming `n` is not the least number for which seeding is done. Check my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct to do so, except for the case n = 0.
Let `get_calls(k,n)` denote the function which takes two arguments `n` and `k` and returns the number of calls made to fib(n) in the calculation of fib(k).
It is important to observe that: fib(0) is only called by fib(2) hence,

- *get_calls(k,0) = get_calls(k,2)*
- **Base Case**: *get_calls(k,k-1)=1.*
- **Recurrence Relation**: *get_calls(k,m) = get_calls(k-1,m) + get_calls(k-2,m).*

Implementation of the method

```
int get_calls(int k,int n)
{     
      if(n>k)  return 0;
      else if(n==0)  return get_calls(k,2);
      else if ((n==k-1)||(n==k))  return 1;
      return get_calls(k-1,n) + get_calls(k-2,n);
}
```

This function mimics the working of the function fib

**Claim:** *get_calls(n+m,n) = fib(m+1)*

> We'll prove this by strong form of induction on m. For `m=1` it holds i.e. get_calls(n+1,n) = 1 = fib(2).
> Now, let it also holds for all natural numbers `m<p`. But that means that
> `get_calls(n+p-1,n) = fib(p)` and `get_calls(n+p-2,n) = fib(p-1)`
> which gives
> `get_calls(n+p,n) = get_calls(n+p-1,n) + get_calls(n+p-2,n) = fib(p-1) + fib(p) = fib(p+1)`

Putting m = k-n in the above formulla gives the required result.

Hence, for `n!=0` and `n<=k`, `get_calls(k,n)=fib(k-n+1)` and `get_calls(k,0) = get_calls(k,2) = fib(k-2+1) = fib(k-1)`.

Comment: The given program fails for k=6 and n=2. Expected output - 5, Actual Output - 3

Comment: As far as code is concerned, the one by @OS2 works perfect.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Now it has been corrected. The problem was with the base cases.

Answer (score 0):

$ cc fib.c -o fib && ./fib

3 occurrences of fib(3) in fib(6)

```
#include <stdio.h>

static size_t N, n, target;

size_t fib(size_t n)
{
  if (n == target)
    N++;

  if (n < 2)
    return n;

  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
                                                                                                                                                                                               
int main()
{
  target = 3;
  n = 6;
  size_t result;
  /* target < n + 1 */
  if (target < n + 1)
    result = fib(n);

  printf("%ld occurrences of fib(%ld) in fib(%ld)\n", N, target, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code works correctly! But can you help generalizing a formula for the same?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a purely mathematical expression for this. You might be able to show by induction if one exists by running the program over a number of samples and extrapolating an expression. My gut feel is there isn't. I can come back to this.

Comment: Even I don't think there's a formula for the same. I have always found this approach unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the answer by instrumenting your code with a `printf` statement:

```
int fib(int n)
{
    static int fibcount;
    printf("fib() called for the %dth time with argument %d.\n", ++fibcount, n);
    if (n <= 1) return n; 
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```